# jsPDF and Rails Download HTML Content

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jspdf

I'm trying to download the content of a blog post into a PDF using jsPDF. I'd prefer to do this via JavaScript since I use Heroku as my webhost and it will make things complicated.

Here is my code that is not working:

```
<script>

$(function() {
  $('.button').on('click',function(){   

    var doc = new jsPDF();

    doc.setFontSize(12);
    doc.text(20, 20, <%= @post.content %>);
    doc.save(<%= @post.name %>);

});
});


</script>
```

Comment: Just saying ITS NOT WORKING is not very helpful, please add what errors you are getting and also some explanation of your code and exact needed output would be needed to help. I can see you are putting @post.content in the pdf, but we dont know what is content there. Please add those details and tag me, i might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You have the arguments for [text()](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF.html#text) the wrong way round. As the docs I've linked say, it takes `text(text, x, y, optionsopt, transform)`, try moving `@post.content` first.

As a side note, I suggest you try generating from html instead of using the text() function which only handles strings.

Comment: How would I generate from HTML?

Comment: Check the documentation I've linked, there is a fromHtml function

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to surround the ERB tags with quotes to output valid JavaScript. For example: `“<%= @post.content %>”`. If the content itself has quotes, then try `<%= @post.content.to_json %>`.

Comment: isnt this a better option `<%= escape_javascript @post.content%>`.